# Use old camera API on lollipop

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an app that use Camera API that works perfectly on a nexus 7 with kitkat, but after update to lollipop my app crash. 
I've decide to use new Camera2 API without success: code works well on a nexus5 but fail on nexus 7.
So i would use old API until i find out where's the problem with new api.
Portion of code that crash is when i initialize camera surface:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();


    Camera.Size result = getBestPreviewSize(params, width, height);

    Log.i("TAG", surfaceView.getWidth() + " " + surfaceView.getHeight());

    params.setPreviewSize(result.width, result.height);
    params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    params.setJpegQuality(100);
    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    // params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
    // params.setp
    params.setPictureSize(dpWidth, dpWidth);
    // default orientation is in landscape
    params.setRotation(90);

    mCamera.setParameters(params);

    mCamera.startPreview();

}
```

crash is on setParameters() instruction:

```
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543): Process: it.ictinnova.hipstamemostylist, PID: 31543
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1876)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at it.ictinnova.hipstamemostylist.ScattaFoto.surfaceChanged(ScattaFoto.java:137)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:590)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:176)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1956)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-18 10:44:54.130: E/AndroidRuntime(31543):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

What's wrong?
this is the same code i used on kitcat

Answer (score 0):

what returns if there is not best preview size in the function of getBestPreviewSize().
maybe,code control resolution of the display and the real machine test resolution is different.
try to annotate the code "params.setPreviewSize(result.width, result.height);" and run the code.